# Dereferencing pointer does break strict anti-aliasing rules using Berkeley sockets

Tags: c, compiler-warnings, berkeley-sockets

I've got code that looks something like this, where addr is a sockaddr*:

```
struct sockaddr_in *sin = (struct sockaddr_in *) addr;
const char *IP=inet_ntoa(sin -> sin_addr);
```

I believe this is very typical code for using Berkeley sockets.

However, when I compile this, I'm getting the following warning:
`dereferencing pointer 'sin' does break strict anti-aliasing rules`

Searching online, I find some discussion of the fact that the way I'm doing things is pretty typical, but this compiler warning also is pretty real and not a good thing.

What's the proper way to redo this code to fix the warning, and not just silence it?

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue - it looks like a bug in gcc.

I was able to get around it by using

```
(*sin).sin_addr
```

instead of

```
sin->sin_addr
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is a know problem with gcc and sockets. The problem basically seems to be that the way this ip[46] stuff is designed is incompatible with the assumptions that the gcc people think they can deduce about aliasing of pointers.

I usually get away with this by first taking a pointer on the `struct`

```
struct in_addr* act = &(sin->sin_addr);
```

and then using `*act`.

Comment: If gcc doesn't give you the same warning when you use *act, either you didn't enable the same warnings that the original poster did, or you found a bug in gcc.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how you've used `struct sockaddr`, I think either your code is broken, or gcc is broken. `struct sockaddr` and `struct sockaddr_in` have a common initial element (`sa_family`/`sin_family`) so it does not violate aliasing rules if you have accessed only this element through both pointers; doing so is permitted by C99. Moreover, `struct sockaddr` has no other elements you're allowed to access. It's largely an opaque type for primitive socket address polymorphism. If you have been poking around at implementation-specific internals in `struct sockaddr`, or worse yet, if you declared a `struct sockaddr` object rather than just a pointer or performed copying between such objects, your code is broken. If you didn't, and gcc is giving a warning claiming you've broken aliasing rules, then gcc's warning generation is broken. I surely wouldn't be surprised if it's the latter.

Comment: @R. first I don't think that it is stated that `sa_family/sin_family` is a common initial element. They must be present both, with identical values. Then the access as the OP gave it *is* a violation of aliasing rules, basically he is doing `((struct sockaddr_in *)addr)->sin_addr` which is a common idiom to do such things.

Comment: Casting a pointer and then dereferencing it is, by itself, **never** a violation of aliasing rules. Only if you also dereferenced it though the original type can aliasing rules have been violated. Regardless of whether POSIX guarantees that `*_family` is a common initial element, in practice it **is**, and gcc, having the structure definition, knows this. So my claim about no aliasing rules having been violated is correct.

Comment: 'They must be present both, with identical values' doesn't mean anything. You're talking about the same piece of memory. Of course the values are the same.

Answer (score -2):

If your header file and your compiler are both parts of the same C or C++ implementation, complain to your vendor and ask them to put a suitable #pragma in their header file to silence their compiler.  As implementor, they're allowed to play games like that, as long as they provide a conforming implementation.

If your header file and your compiler came from two separate C or C++ implementations, you're lucky that things work as well as they do, and you have to solve it yourself.

Comment: Sockets are not part of a compiler implementation but part of the operating system.

Comment: Where the programmer has "#include <something.h>", either that header file something.h is part of a C or C++ implementation, or else the programmer is lucky that things work as well as they do and the programmer has to solve it theirself.

Comment: That's only true for #include files that are part of the language, e.g. stdlib.h. Socket include files are part of a sockets SDK, not the compiler.